Jetpack Compose: AnimateAsFloat not working
I want to animate/translate my ImageView only once and for that I have written this code:
@Composable
fun SunsetBox(panchangData: Data?, targetProgress: Float) {
Box(
modifier = Modifier
.requiredWidth(153.dp)
.requiredHeight(136.dp)
) {
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

    // Define the animation
    val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = 0f,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 10000)
    )

    // Update the progress based on the animation
    LaunchedEffect(animatedProgress) {
        progress = animatedProgress
    }


    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_sunset_sun),
        contentDescription = "Sunset",
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
            .graphicsLayer {
                // Translate the sun image based on the progress
                translationY = (1 - progress) * 20.dp.toPx() // Reverse translation
                alpha = progress // Reverse alpha
            })
}

I want to move/translate the image from 1f to 0f but the code immediately gives 0f position. I don't know why. However whenever I am running this code with infinite transition it is working absolutely right. Can someone pls help me. I have tried very hard to do this.
var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    // Define the animation
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val animationValue by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1f,
        targetValue = 0f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 10000)
        )
    )

    // Update the progress based on the animation
    progress = animationValue

with this infinite case it works absolutely perfect. I want to run it only once. After completing it, I am using this SunsetBox composable in some another composable.

You should set the target value of animateFloatAsState to progress. And in your LaunchedEffect you should than set the progress to 0f.
And also do not use the key animatedProgress in Launched effect.
(I missed this. You of course need to use the animatedProgress value for your graphicsLayer.)
So correct code should look like this:
var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }

// Define the animation
val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = progress,
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 10000)
)

// Update the progress based on the animation
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    progress = 0f
}
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_sunset_sun),
    contentDescription = "Sunset",
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
        .graphicsLayer {
            // Translate the sun image based on the progress
            translationY = (1 - animatedProgress) * 20.dp.toPx() // Reverse translation
            alpha = animatedProgress // Reverse alpha
        })


Are you sure. Is this working for you ?

Sorry yes i missed the part inside of the Image
